# Did Luke practise his physician skills in Acts 28:9?

Tags: acts

Acts 28:7 There was an estate nearby that belonged to Publius, the chief official of the island. He welcomed us to his home and showed us generous hospitality for three days. 8His father was sick in bed, suffering from fever and dysentery. **Paul** went in to see him and, after prayer, placed his hands on him and **healed** him. 9When this had happened, the rest of the sick on the island came and were cured. 10They honored **us** in many ways; and when we were ready to sail, they furnished us with the supplies we needed.

Did Luke work as a physician and get paid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did Luke practice as a physician in Acts?  Not according to Acts 28:7-10.  In facts we know several things about this incident:

- Paul healed miraculously by the power of God in V9
- Luke is never mentioned as being active in the healing in this passage
- The illness was dysentery (δυσεντερία) a disorder of the bowels (specifically a type of gastroenteritis that results in diarrhea with blood) presumably caused by a serious microbial infection, was beyond the capability of common medicine in the first century (except to hydrate the patient and hope they recovered naturally) but has become more treatable in modern times with antimicrobial drugs.  Thus, it is unlikely that Luke would have been even able to treat the sick in this case.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysentery
- There is no mention of payment (money) here, except that the locals greatly appreciated Paul's divine cures and so the locals "honored" Paul, Luke and their travelling companions and gave them supplies.

This is not to say that Luke did not practice medicine at times, but not in this case.